# make a background image clickable without making contents clickable

Tags: image, background, clickable

I desperately need to make the background image of a site clickable, but I don't want everything (i.e. the contents of the site) to be clickable.  how do I make it so that just the background image clicks to a website with making the contents click to that website as well.

Comment: What is "clickable"? Do you mean to hyperlink?